# Xcode 4, Cocoa Title bar removing from interface builders disables textView from editing

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4

I am designing an application without a title bar, however when I remove the title bar using interface builder in Xcode 4 , it causes the editable fields (the ones I tried are textView, and textField) not being editable, despite editable checked in there properties? why this happens and is there anyway to prevent it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to subclass your window and overwrite the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    // because the window is borderless, we have to make it active
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow {
    // because the window is borderless, we have to make it active
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 4 and general tips about how to do this in 2018:

The `canBecomeKeyWindow` and `canBecomeMainWindow` methods no longer exist on an NSWindow. They have since been replaced by stored properties called `canBecomeKey` and `canBecomeMain`. Because they are stored, if you want to override them you can do so by making them computed properties, like this:

```
override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
    return true
}

override var canBecomeMain: Bool {
    return true
}
```