# Subviews become disabled when title bar is hidden

Tags: macos, cocoa

Writing app in XCode for OSX using OSX 10.8 SDK. All of my Windows work fine, until I use Interface Building to get rid of the title bar in the nib (I uncheck the `Title Bar` param on the Attributes Inspector of the window element). The windows still show, but all the subviews are disabled.  I can no longer input text and process bars are all greyed out.

Does anyone know why this is happening? and how to have a Window without a title bar, but with all subviews enabled?

Here is what my view looks like with a title bar:
[image]

And here's what it looks like without:
[image]

As you can see, everything is disabled.

---

**Update**

Someone asked about code to display windows. For this example I didn't use any code. For the two screens above here are the steps I followed:

1. Created a new cocoa application using XCode. (Automatically creates a xib).
2. Dragged out two controls (Text field and progress bar) onto the existing window.
3. Ran, and took a screen shot
4. Closed and checked off the `Title Bar` attribute for the window.
5. Restarted the app. Took the second screen shot.

Comment: How are you 'getting rid of the title bar in their windows'?

Comment: Interface Builder. I'm unchecking the `Title Bar` check on the attributes inspector of the NSWindow object.

Comment: Please show the code you use to display the window.

Comment: Just used interface builder with a new cocoa app. See update for details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an answer for this question at this link:

[Xcode 4, Cocoa Title bar removing from interface builders disables textView from editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115811/xcode-4-cocoa-title-bar-removing-from-interface-builders-disables-textview-from)

If you read the documentation for NSWindow you can see that the methods canBecomeKeyWindow and canBecomeMainWindow return NO if there is no title bar.  Sub-classing NSWindow and over-riding these methods will make it so they can become key windows.

There is sample code on how to subclass these windows in apple's documentation website, or in xcode if you have documentation installed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/canBecomeKeyWindow

Search for canBecomeKeyWindow in the above link and there will be sample code included that will help explain the process.

Comment: The sample code isn't at the linked address anymore